# Jcraft 1.5 SFTP overwrite Failure ID 4

Tags: java, sftp, put, jsch, overwrite

My overwrite isnt working and returns a Failure 4 ID. I can write to this destination with out any issues but when the overwire keeps failing. When I use winscp with the same user creds being used here i can I can write and overwrite without issues. Not sure I understand whats going on here with my overwrite option. If the file is in there and overwrite is true then the file with the same name should be overwritten but its not working. I'm using Jcraft 1.50 and I don't want to upgrade to 1.54 because i was having the same issue with that version before i reverted back the library.

```
//connect
try {
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword( password );
    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
    channel.connect();
    sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    //make sure that file does not exist or 
    //user wants to overwrite the file
    testStream = sftpChannel.get(destination);
    if (testStream != null && !overwrite) {
        throw new SftpException(ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_OP_UNSUPPORTED, "File already exists");
    }
} catch (SftpException e) {
    if (e.id == ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE){
        //file does not yet exist. continue.
    } else {
        resultComments = "SFTP Exception " + e.getMessage();
        status = RunResult.FAIL;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (JSchException e) {
    resultComments = "Jsch Exception " + e.getMessage();
    status = RunResult.FAIL;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    //if file does not exist or overwrite selected, transfer file
    if (testStream == null || overwrite) {
        ByteArrayInputStream fileByteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByteArray);
        if (sftpChannel !=  null) {
            String workingDirectory = destination.substring(0, destination.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            String fileName = destination.substring(destination.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, destination.length());
            sftpChannel.cd(workingDirectory);
            sftpChannel.put(fileByteInputStream, fileName, sftpChannel.OVERWRITE);        
            try {
                fileByteInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                resultComments = "SFTP Exception: Unable to close Input Stream." + e.getMessage();
                status = RunResult.FAIL;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sftpChannel.exit();
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
} catch (SftpException e) {
    resultComments = "SFTP Exception " + e.getMessage();
    status = RunResult.FAIL;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed the issue. Seems as if this method.....

```
sftpChannel.put(fileByteInputStream, fileName, sftpChannel.OVERWRITE);
```

does not work properly. Even though Jcraft documentation plainly says that...

```
put(String src, String dst, int mode)
//Uploads a file.
```

when i change it to a different put method as so....

```
sftpChannel.put(fileByteInputStream, fileName, null, sftpChannel.OVERWRITE);
```

my overwrite issues seem to go away by using the put method...

```
put(String src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode)
//Uploads a file.
```

I'm able to transfer with out getting any failures when the file already exists and i want to overwrite it.